# Getting Multiple times output

Tags: apex, batch

In this batch Apex code, I updated **Mr.** infront of the name if student is **Male** and **Mrs.** infront of the name if student is **Female** but at in output **Mr.** or **Mrs.** is getting multiple times. Please give me the suggestions to remove the multiple times of getting **Mr.** and **Mrs.** and get only once.

**The above is the code that i was did**

```
public class UpdateGender implements database.batchable<sobject> {

        
        public database.querylocator start(database.batchableContext abc){
            string a = 'SELECT Student_Id__c, Name, Gender__c FROM Student__c';
            return database.getquerylocator(a);
        }
        
        public void execute(database.batchableContext def, list<Student__c> x){
            for(Student__c a : x){
                if(a.Gender__c == 'Male'){
                    a.Name = 'Mr.'+a.Name;
                }
                else if(a.Gender__c == 'Female'){
                    a.Name = 'Mrs.'+a.Name;
                }
            }
            upsert x;
        }
        
        public void finish(database.batchableContext ghi){
            system.debug('Finish::!');
        }
    }
```

**The above image is multiple times getting Mr. and Mrs. in output**
[image: Multiple times Mr.]
[image: Multiple times Mr.]

Comment: Seems like you are running the batch multiple time and as SOQL query in your start method doesn't have any filters, it pick's up updated record. One simpler fix would be to filter out updates records with a WHERE clause to query to filter out records that starts with `Mr.` or `Mrs.`.

Comment: as a good practice do not use upsert, you are working on existing records it will always be a update operation

Comment: @Arihant Kumar Seraogi ok sir thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might be running the batch multiple times this is getting appended. Try to avoid updating the records which already has those prefixes as below by adding this extra condition  `!(a.name.startswith('Mr.'))` as below

```
public class UpdateGender implements database.batchable<sobject> {

    
    public database.querylocator start(database.batchableContext abc){
        string a = 'SELECT  Name, Gender__c FROM Student__c';
        return database.getquerylocator(a);
    }
    
    public void execute(database.batchableContext def, list<Student__c> x){
        for(Student__c a : x){
            if(a.Gender__c == 'Male' && !(a.name.startswith('Mr.'))){
                a.Name = 'Mr.'+a.Name;
            }
            else if(a.Gender__c == 'Female' && !(a.name.startswith('Mrs.'))){
                a.Name = 'Mrs.'+a.Name;
            }
        }
        update x;
    }
    
    public void finish(database.batchableContext ghi){
        system.debug('Finish::!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir !

Comment: Filter in query would be better, otherwise it will unnecessary retrieve all unwanted records.

Comment: @Raul, Yes correct it would be better to filter it in query .